# is there any default temporary tablespace created when create user?

Tags: oracle

I use windows 7 and oracle 11g , so when i create a user in oracle :

```
create user test2 identified by test2;
```

so as i know with this syntax , oracle will create a defualt tablespace for this user , and does this syntax also create a temporary tablespace or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TEST2 won't have a tablespace or temp tablespace created for them, but they will be assigned tablespaces for them to use for storing segments and doings maths/temp operations.

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-USER.html#GUID-F0246961-558F-480B-AC0F-14B50134621C):

> Specify the default tablespace for objects that are created in the
>   user's schema. If you omit this clause, then the user's objects are
>   stored in the database default tablespace. If no default tablespace
>   has been specified for the database, then the user's objects are
>   stored in the SYSTEM tablespace.

Same goes for TEMP

If you want to see what they're currently set to -

```
SELECT *
  FROM database_properties
 WHERE property_name LIKE 'DEFAULT%SPACE%';
```

You can also just pull up these values in SQL Developer using the DBA panel the Current Database Properties page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this new user will share the default temporary tablespace with the other users that are using it already. This query shows you which temporary tablespace is the default temporary tablespace. HTH KR Peter

```
SELECT PROPERTY_VALUE
FROM DATABASE_PROPERTIES
WHERE PROPERTY_NAME = 'DEFAULT_TEMP_TABLESPACE';
```